# where is zeppelin-env.sh file in docker?

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I download the zeppelin with Docker hub.
right now zeppelin is running with Docker
where should I find the zeppelin-env.sh file in Docker?

If I installed it with installed file I should find the installed location 
but not sure how to find it with docker install

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to know where it exists *on your host filesystem*? We'd need to know way more to answer that, f/e, which storage backend you have Docker configured to use; depending on the answer to that question, it may not exist on your filesystem at all (f/e, if you're using a backend that creates its own device-mapper or LVM pools).

Comment: Frankly, the better approach is to not care where it's stored, but instead use Docker's tooling to extract it regardless of location (instead of trying to figure out where it exists at the OS level to use OS-level tooling).

Comment: I try to use spark master on zeppelin but when I change the inter pretor on zeppelin. it keep saying no spark application is running